# Handling large numbers in Julia

Tags: julia

In Python, I can do the following to get the sum of all digits in `N`, where `N=99999 ** 99999`. The sum can be obtained with `sum(map(int,str(N)))`.

How can i find the sum of all digits in N with Julia?

Comment: in Julia, N=99999 ^ 99999 gives a -ve value

Comment: It gives negative? It gives wrong answer for me but still positive.

Answer (score 10):

You are hitting integer overflow. Try using `BigInt`s.

```
julia> N=digits(big(99999)^99999)
499995-element Array{Int64,1}:
 9
 9
 9
 9
 9
 8
 9
 9
 9
 9
 ⋮
 5
 0
 8
 2
 1
 8
 8
 7
 6
 3
```

Notice that

```
julia> typemax(Int64)
9223372036854775807
```

which is far too small, but `BigInt`s are arbitrary sized. `big(i)` turns `i` into a big (`BigFloat` if it's a float, and `BigInt` if it's an integer). Julia does not default to using bigs/arbitrary sized numbers since they are quite slow, but if you invoke them then the type stability of most dispatches will propagate the big type, so `big(i)^j` will end up big.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little old, but I found an interesting performance improvement that can be useful for new users (or that more advanced users can explain), at least those using Julia 1.5 or earlier.

By default, Julia casts "99999" to `Int64`. However, 99999⁹⁹⁹⁹⁹ is a big number that doesn't fit into an `Int64` variable (that supports up to 2⁶³). You have, then, to use `big(99999)` or equivalently `BigInt(99999)` (what Python does automatically).

One could write

```julia
julia> sum(digits(big(99999)^99999))
```

and it definitely works.

**EDIT:** As rafak pointed out, Julia 1.6 optimized `digits(n::BigInt)` and the problem is gone. Here are the new benchmarks:

- Python 3.8.5:

```python
>>> %timeit sum(map(int,str(99999**99999)))
4.36 s ± 51.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

- Julia 1.6.1:

```julia
julia> @benchmark sum(digits(big(99999)^99999))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  13.56 MiB
  allocs estimate:  990
  --------------
  minimum time:     40.200 ms (0.84% GC)
  median time:      41.894 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        42.006 ms (0.27% GC)
  maximum time:     44.410 ms (1.59% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          119
  evals/sample:     1
```

I'll keep the old benchmarks for historical reasons.

---

In Julia 1.5, benchmarking a little, I found:

- Python:

```py
>>> %timeit sum(map(int,str(99999**99999)))
4.9 s ± 5.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

- Julia 1.5:

```julia
julia> @benchmark sum(digits(big(99999)^99999))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  142.75 GiB
  allocs estimate:  5343475
  --------------
  minimum time:     79.833 s (3.24% GC)
  median time:      79.833 s (3.24% GC)
  mean time:        79.833 s (3.24% GC)
  maximum time:     79.833 s (3.24% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          1
  evals/sample:     1
```

I know. Julia is the "above the light speed", "faster than C and Fortran" language. Why would it be (considerably) slower than Python, the "turtle language"? And how can we deal with this huge amount of memory allocated?
Let's try the "pythonic" algorithm, rewritten in Julia 1.5:

```julia
julia> sum(map(x -> parse(Int32, x), collect(string(big(99999)^99999))))
```

I know that it sounds very strange and counter-intuitive, but numbers say everything. Here my results.

- Julia ("Pythonic" way):

```julia
julia> @benchmark sum(map(x -> parse(Int32, x), collect(string(big(99999)^99999))))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  13.56 MiB
  allocs estimate:  991
  --------------
  minimum time:     62.130 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      63.111 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        63.183 ms (0.24% GC)
  maximum time:     66.055 ms (0.68% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          80
  evals/sample:     1
```

**Remarks.**

- `%timeit` is an IPython magic. `@benchmark` is a macro implemented by [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) (need install).
- In the last Julia benchmark, memory allocation can be improved using `Int8` to map the string, but the time is fairly the same.
- New and "historic" benchmarks should not be compared, as they were done in different machines.

---

In summary, it can be done in Julia both with a simple but slow code and with a verbose but fast one. I can't explain exactly why though.

Comment: The `digits` function was recently optimized for `BigInt`, in Julia 1.6, and `sum(digits(big(99999)^99999))` becomes slightly faster than your "pythonic way".

Comment: Interesting. And what about memory allocation?

Answer (score -2):

So, to summarise.

```
sum(digits(big(99999)^99999))
```

Comment: To summarize what? This post is unclear as to how it presents a solution to OP's problem.