# Julia computation does not give the correct answer

Tags: julia

When I tried to calculate

```
10^999
```

in Julia 1.8.2. I got an answer of 0. I think this could be due to the storage issue (10^99 is too large)? But how do we avoid this type of error automatically, is there any way to tell Julia to stop calculating 10^99 instead of returning me a value of 0? I just want to avoid such error in my code.

In fact, if I try to calculate

```
1E999
```

Julia will tell me `syntax: overflow in numeric constant "1E999"`, which is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/exponent-operator-failing-for-large-exponents/88286

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Integers) discuss how integer overflow is handled in Julia. The short version boils down to the simple fact that checking for overflow on every integer computation causes too large a performance hit to include in the language. It's up to the user to be aware of this and use `BigInt` where necessary. Other performance-oriented languages typically treat integers like this too.

Comment: related questions: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21127770/ 
2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50023856/ 
3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71610363/ 
4. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30751267/ 
5. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62132562/

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation and references!

Answer (score 1):

While the reasons have been discussed in comments and there are links to similar questions just not that you could try:

```
julia> big(10)^99
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

or define your own primitive type

```
julia> using BitIntegers

julia> BitIntegers.@define_integers 1024
@uint1024_str (macro with 1 method)

julia> Int1024(10)^99
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Or use https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/SaferIntegers.jl